# Python, ElasticSearch: Delete only index data for last 7 days, not dashboards, index-patterns

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am working on AWS, where we have ElasticSearch instances for logs. Currently, we don't need logs for more than 7 days. So we are deleting them via a Lambda Script written in python-3. But along with that, it's also deleting index-patterns and dashboard config along with it.

How can I only delete index-data, not index-pattern and dashboard data. Any ideas?

Code:

```
import boto3
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
import curator


region = 'eu-central-1' # For example, us-west-1
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

index_list = curator.IndexList(es)

index_list.filter_by_age(source='creation_date', direction='older', unit='days', unit_count=7)

   if index_list.indices:
        curator.DeleteIndices(index_list).do_action()
```

My index-pattern is filebeat-*

Answer (score 0):

For these types of routine and repetitive tasks [index lifecycle](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) comes very handy, AWS Elasticsearch also has [index state management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/ism.html) which you can use.

Specifically to your use-case, [curator's delete indices API](https://curator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actionclasses.html#deleteindices) is what you may be looking for.

Comment: Index lifecycle is only applicable for 7.10, state for 6.8, we are still on 6.4 for compataibility reason. I am already calling delete indices API as shown in my code, which is deleting everything. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you are not able to you AWS ES ISM feature due to old es version:

Index-patterns and dashboard config are stored in your .kibana* indices. So you need to filter those indices from your "index_list" and delete the remaining ones.

Use the "exclude" parameter for the same:

```
IndexList.filter_by_age(source='name', direction=None, timestring=None, unit=None, unit_count=None, field=None, stats_result='min_value', epoch=None, exclude=False, unit_count_pattern=False)
```

https://curator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html

So your filter call would look like:

```
index_list.filter_by_age(source='creation_date', direction='older', unit='days', unit_count=7, exclude='.kibana*')
```

Note: I haven’t tested the above code, please test it before deploying in production environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will test this. :-)

Comment: This didn't work, it removed literally everything, nothing was spared..... it even removed kibana index patterns, etc

Answer (score 0):

You're basically going through with `creatoin_date` as the filter. So it will collect all the indices and all the content accordingly to the timestapm given.

You could use `name` filter instead.

```
index_list_cw.filter_by_age(source='name', direction='older', timestring='%Y.%m.%d', unit='days', unit_count=7)
```

Please set it up the timestring value accordingly and it will list all the indices.
After you can simply call delete funtion.

curator.DeleteIndices(index_list).do_action()

Please always refer options, https://curator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html